# Buying a top level domain specific to my industry, will it improve my seo ratings?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, top-level-domains

Currently we run a few websites selling products in the travel industry using .com and .co.uk extensions.

Would our search rating improve if we were to buy one of the .travel domains ? So we would replace, or more likely supplment the following

```
mycompany.com
myCompany.co.uk
```

with :

```
mycompany.travel
```

Bing and google rankings are, unsurprisingly, our main concerns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short: The .travel domain won't give you any edge in SEO. It might be quite contrary, .com will have an edge in world-wide search, .co.uk might have (underline might) an edge in British Google search.

[Something interesting to read](http://www.seomad.com/SEOBlog/do-different-tlds-affect-seo.html) and [another interesting bit](https://plus.google.com/+MattCutts/posts/4VaWg4TMM5F).

Answer (score 0):

From an SEO perspective, a TLD is a TLD. Your website's ranking won't be improved by buying a TLD about your business (.travel).

You can work on your existing domain in order to improve the SEO of your websites.

Moreover, using TLD related to your country (co.uk) is a good thing to rank better in your country's Google search.

You can learn about domain choices [here](http://www.howtobefound.co.uk/how-to-choose-domain-extension/).

Comment: that link you referenced says "Avoid hyphens", then later it says "For readability sake, a domain name that is longer than 3 words should be separated with hyphens.". Thats a bit naff.

Comment: You're right, I have changed the link.